# How do you unschedule a task in automator?

Tags: macos, automator

I scheduled an automatic backup with Automator, it has run properly and I receive a pop-up notification every day informing about it. Now, I want to stop the task but I do not know where to find the list of scheduled tasks and how to kill them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Automator by itself does not provide scheduling facilities. You'll need to disable the scheduled launch of a workflow using whatever you used to schedule the workflow originally. For example,

- if you used a recurring calendar appointment, you'll need to use Calendar to delete the appointment.
- if you used a third-party application, you'll need to use that application to disable the schedule.

Comment: Thanks. I simply did not look in the right place. I do not use Apple "Calendar" so I could not see that I have a recurrent appointment to perform the backup.